# Can't get NUnit tests to run on Build Agent

Tags: nunit-3.0

I have read all of the posts on this forum on this subject and still have not figured this out. The error I am getting is:

Edit: In the log I see "Run VS Test Runner". Should this be a different Test Runner?
"No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."

My environment is NUnit3 version 3.2.1 on TFS 2013 using VS 2013 targeting .NET4. My tests run fine when building on the local machine. I have the NUnit3 Test Adaptor installed on the Build Agent machine and I have a runsettings file. Queued builds work without error but the tests are not being run. I'm pretty sure that I have the "Test sources spec" correct in the Build Definition because I get an different error if I put something incorrect in that field. Where would I find a log... or how do I enable verbose logging that would expound on this error. Right now I have no idea where to look. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the nUnit Test Adapter Nuget package -

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/

Comment: There may be an access issue getting to those files for the agent. In general, I always recommend using Nuget packages instead of installing more software on build/test agents.  Updating is easier via Nuget and you avoid version conflicts with other projects.

Comment: So you are saying that I should install the nUnit Test Adapter Nuget package on each dev machine instead of on the Build Agent? I already have it on there too.

Comment: Yes.  Its better because then all the dependencies are explicitly defined for the project.  All a developer has to do is pull the source down, restore Nuget packages and it should build & run tests successfully.  Same applies for the build agent.  When you rely on installed software it is less clear what is required.  If you have already added the Nuget package and it still doesn't work.  Verify the test assembly is being built and its name appropriately.  The build will have a test assembly filter.

Comment: Thanks much @chief7. That gets me to my next problem which is "Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests". I will accept your answer above. Any help on my new error would be appreciated. Otherwise, if I don't figure that out I will post another question.

Comment: Looks like that problem is due to fact that I have NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0 and need 3.2.1..

Comment: Glad I could help.  Will be happy to help with the new issue but please submit it as a new question so other can find it too.  If you still need help.